# Media Queries CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For some reason my media queries do not resize my site correctly when viewing from an iphone or mobile device, i get the tablet version of the site on an iphone. The media queries work fine for tablet and perfectly when shrinking a browser window.

Have I missed anything?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/*styling here*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 740px) {
/*Tablet styling here*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 739px) and (min-width: 0px) {
/*Mobile styling here*/
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. You can try the LESS skeleton stylesheet: http://lessframework.com/

Comment: Make sure the mobile browser wants to be supplied with a mobile version of the site. If the user has chosen not to, the browser will use a higher screen width and parse the normal stylesheet.

Comment: Try to write first for small devices then for higher resolution & use meta viewport. Hope all these help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/),
and let me know whether it is working or not

You need to specify device width.

Comment: [Another Related Source](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries/)

Comment: Using device width doesn't seem to work maybe because i'm using a virtual tester called MITE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to specify it as 'min-device-width'.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 739px) and (min-device-width: 0px) {
    /*Mobile styling here*/
}
```